# Current role name in prompt

Tags: postgresql, prompt

I add to my `PROMPT1` and `PROMPT2` the `%n` parameter to show the current user.
I thought that it works like `SELECT CURRENT_USER;` but when I changed my role with `SET ROLE role_name;` I noticed that user in my prompt doesn't changed but in `CURRENT_USER` is role name as I expected.

Is there any way to display in prompt the current role instead of current user?

Answer (score 0):

%n doesn't mean CURRENT_USER, it means SESSION_USER. However, even if you change SESSION_USER using "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION" - prompt doesn't change.

I guess you can't do anything with it without recompiling psql.